# bulk insert data with Postgres into QuestDB

Tags: questdb

How does one bulk insert data with Postgres into QuestDB?
The following does not work

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (employee_id INT, last_name STRING,first_name STRING);
INSERT INTO employees
(employee_id, last_name, first_name)
VALUES
(10, 'Anderson', 'Sarah'),(11, 'Johnson', 'Dale');
```

Answer (score 1):

For inserting data in bulk, there are a few options. You can use `CREATE AS SELECT` to [bulk insert from an existing table](https://questdb.io/docs/get-started/first-database#inserting-data) which is closest to your example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees
AS (SELECT employee_id, last_name, first_name FROM existing_table)
```

Or you can use prepared statements, there are full working examples in a few languages in the [QuestDB Postgres documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/develop/insert-data#postgres-compatibility), here is a snippet from the Python example:

```py
# insert 10 records
for x in range(10):
  cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO example_table
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s);
    """, (dt.datetime.utcnow(), "python example", x))
# commit records
connection.commit()
```

Or you can [bulk import from CSV](https://questdb.io/docs/develop/insert-data#imp-endpoint), i.e.:

```sh
curl -F data=@data.csv http://localhost:9000/imp
```